# Why is my form trying to submit to the wrong endpoint?

Tags: python, html, mongodb, dictionary, flask

I have a python script and a mongoDB instance.
With flask I now want to list all the items of my database on a webpage and use a second webpage to trigger the script to add an other item.

But everytime I click "submit" on the "/add" page, I get a "Method not allowed" and I can see, that it tries to submit it to "/" instead of "/add" ..

**script.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import requests, json, sys, getopt, smtplib
from os import system, name
from pathlib import Path
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(port = 27017)
db = client.amazonProducts
allitems = []
allMyItems = []
for document in db.items.find():
  allitems.append(document["name"])

def addItem():
    for dbWishList in db.wishlist.find():
        url = dbWishList["wishlist"]
    items = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)

    if items:

        for item in items:
            itemName = str(item["name"])
            itemPrice = item["new-price"]
            itemUrl = str(item['link'])
            if itemPrice:
                itemPrice = str(itemPrice[26: ])
                itemPrice = str(itemPrice[: itemPrice.find("<")])
                itemPriceF = str(itemPrice.replace(".", ""))
                itemPriceF = str(itemPriceF.replace("€", ""))
                itemPriceF = str(itemPriceF.replace("\xa0", ""))
                itemPriceF = str(itemPriceF.replace(",", ".")).replace("\xf6", "")
                itemPriceFi = float(itemPriceF)
                itemUrl = itemUrl[: itemUrl.find("?coliid")]
                itemNameF = itemName.replace('&quot;', '"')
                itemNameFi = itemNameF.replace("&amp;amp;", "&")
                itemNameFi = itemNameFi.replace("&uuml;", "ue").replace("&ouml;", "oe").replace("&auml;", "ae").replace("&nbsp;", " ").replace("&ndash;", "-")

            amazonItem = {
                'name': itemNameFi,
                'url': itemUrl,
                'price': itemPriceFi,
                'maxPrice': 0
            }

            db.items.insert_one(amazonItem)

        for document in db.items.find():
            allMyItems.append(document["name"])
        return allMyItems

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():

  return render_template("index.html", len = len(allitems), allitems = allitems)

app.run(use_reloader = True, debug = True)

app.config["DEBUG"] = True
@app.route("/add", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def secPage():

    errors = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        global testingVar
        testingVar = None

        try:
            testingVar = string(request.form["testingVar"])
        except:
            errors += "<p>{!r} is not a string.</p>\n".format(request.form["testingVar"])
        if testingVar is not None:
            addItem()
        return render_template("secIndex.html", len = len(allMyItems), allMyItems = allMyItems)
    return '''
        <html>
            <body>
                {errors}
                <p>What you wanna do?:</p>
                <form method="post" action=".">
                    <p><input name="testingVar" /></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Do magic" /></p>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    '''.format(errors=errors)
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>For loop in Flask</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 

        <ul> 
        <!-- For loop logic of jinja template -->
        {%for i in range(0, len)%} 

            <li>{{allitems[i]}}</li> 
        {%endfor%} 

        </ul> 

    </body> 
</html>
```

**secIndex.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>For loop in Flask</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 

        <!-- For loop logic of jinja template -->
        <form method="post" action=".">
            <p><input name="testingVar" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Do magic" /></p>
        </form>


    </body> 
</html>
```

The items are built like:

```py
amazonItem = {
    'name': itemNameFi,
    'url': itemUrl,
    'price': itemPriceFi,
    'maxPrice': 0
}
```

Can anyone here follow me and tell me where my mistake might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form definition you have:

```
<form method="post" action=".">
```

The action attribute needs to have the endpoint you want to send the post request to. In your case, you want

```
<form method="post" action="/add">
```

If you omit the action attribute, it will submit the post request to the current page, so if you are viewing your form from `/add`, you can just use

```
<form method="post">
```